# Any way to get how Domino server stores the date format

Tags: java, datetime, date, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Could some one please let me know whether there is any way where in I can get the response from the Domino server as How the date format is stored.

For example if the domino server stores the date as 02/08/2011 in mm/dd/yyyy format, the Domino server should return the date format as mm/dd/yyyy.

similarly if the domino server stores the date as 08/02/2011 in dd/mm/yyyy format, the Domino server should return the date format as dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "[International class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_INTERNATIONAL_SETTINGS_JAVA.html)" represents the international settings in the operating environment, for example, the Regional Settings in the Windows Control Panel. When settings change in the operating environment, Notes recognizes the new settings immediately. For remote (IIOP) operations (that't what you are doing), these settings represent the session's server.

The "International Class" has the [properties you are looking](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_INTERNATIONAL_SETTINGS_JAVA.html) for:

- isDateDMY returns a boolean value
  that is true if the order of the date
  format is day-month-year.
- isDateMDY returns a boolean value that is true
  if the order of the date format is
  month-day-year.
- isDateYMD returns a boolean value that is true if the
  order of the date format is
  year-month-day.

But if you trying to get values out of a a [Notes document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS_JAVA.html), you could/should use the [DateTimeValue property](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DATETIMEVALUE_PROPERTY_JAVA.html) of the corresponding [NotesItem](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESITEM_CLASS_JAVA.html), which returns a [NotesDateTime object](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATETIME_CLASS_JAVA.html). And ths object has a [toJavaDate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TOJAVADATE_METHOD_JAVA.html) method - which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Notes 8 running a LotusScript on the server you can use NotesInternational:

http://www.loganmachinists.com/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/fb55765d3fed30a08525731b004a2eaf?OpenDocument

Comment: I am interested to communicate with the domino server thru the java code. Don't want to run any code or script in the system where domino server is installed. Could you pls let me know whether there is any API provided by the domino server to get the date format.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here, but Domino does not store actual Date/Times as 'dd/mm/yyyy' etc, this is purely used when *displaying* Dates and Times for example, when using a DateTime Field, which will also display a proper date/time in the users local format.  i.e. a UK or US user will see the same stored date/time displayed differently in their local format.

In Notes objects, Items, Fields and the Formula Language,  Date/Time is handled as the number of seconds from January 1, 1 AD.

In LotusScript Date/Time is handled as a floating point variant, with the value to the left of the decimal point representing the number of days from January 1, 100 AD and to the right, the fraction of a day from midnight.